# Way to implement real time searching in local data in android

Tags: java, android

I have just started android development and here is my situation elaborately.
Sample data in JSON format:
 {
    "ht_id": 1086,
    "name": "Mobile Phones",
    "rate": 12
  },
  {
    "ht_id": 1111,
    "name": "Primary cells and primary batteries",
    "rate": 28
  },
  {
    "ht_id": 1112,
    "name": "Electric accumulators, including separators therefor, whether or not rectangular (including square)",
    "rate": 28
  }

I have some 250 static records total and planning to ship the same with the app. I want to search if input string is contained in the data and return corresponding "rate" in real time.

As I want to do this in real time, search speed is the utmost criteria.
So, I am wondering how to store data with the app (DB/CSV/text/JSON) and later how to read in memory for super fast retrieval in android app(eg: hashSet)

Comment: I would try it with a database and see if it's fast enough.  File access with solid state storage is very fast.

Comment: As @nasch said, you should try using a local database but combine the search using a loader. Loaders are really really fast and they're easy to use. Please check this link for more info on loaders: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html?hl=en-419

Comment: Thanks a lot bro..will try this